# wpf Line stroke shown blurry

Tags: wpf, xaml, line, shapes, stroke

I made a sample code in VS 2013 preview, I made a line inside a canvas with stroke color of white, but the line is shown so strangely like more thick and not white (almost gray).
same sample I tried it in VS 2010 and it output well.

Can anyone tell me what's going on...?

```
<Canvas Width="200" Height="200" Background="Black">
    <Line X1="30" Y1="60" X2="90" Y2="60" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <Line X1="60" Y1="30" X2="60" Y2="90" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

[image]

//EDIT
when I change the line thickness to 2 or more then it shows perfectly white but with thickness of 2.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same case, but sometimes, images can be shown a bit blurry as well. One way of solving that problem is using the RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode property of your window where you can set the desired quality. But then again, that is a problem that I already encountered with blurry images, not sure if that same solution applies to the situation you just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is our old friend Pixel Snapping. WPF will use a similar technology to `ClearType` to draw lines when they fall on a pixel boundary. This is what you're seeing. The reason why it may change between versions of VS is that they can start your canvas in a different location.

[Dave Relyea has a cool Pixel Snapping Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/05/26/pixel-snapping-the-snapper-element.aspx) to help with just these problems.

Since his control was made for Silverlight, I'd change `UserControl` to `Decorator` for WPF purposes. Just change all references from `Content` to `Child`. That way you won't have to worry about a `ControlTemplate` being applied by somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move it 0.5 pixel down, it may help

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent explanation at http://www.wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html