# WPF Grid renders shadow/border on the left and right side

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a project using wpf. 
The UI design is based on a tile system, where you can drag and drop tiles to specific locations. 
The presentation of the tiles uses a customized TreeView that renders the items as Grids.

looking close to the rendered grid items i recognized that wpf renders the grid with shadows on the left and the right side.

[image: Tile closeup] 
[image: Problem overview]

Does anyone have an idea why there are shadows rendered? For a specific feature i have to color the bottom part of the grid red and it looks awkward cause of the rendered shadow.

Comment: I do not see shadows on given screenshot.

Comment: if you open the screenshot in paint you can see that there is a column of pixels (1px width) on the left side, that is not the same color as the rest of the picture (same on the right side).

Maybe shadow is the wrong word for this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where this tile is on top of some background? Or better one with many tiles. Currently question is pretty unclear: screenshot is poor (doesn't demonstrate the problem clearly), you provide no code/xaml, description is ambiguous (do you mean border, blurring or indeed shadow?).

Comment: @Sinatr I've added the picture "Problem overview", hopefully this will be clear enough.

Comment: Try to google for "wpf blurry", [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17448782/1997232), [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3286214/1997232), etc. TLDR; it seems vertical line is not aligned to device pixels, therefore its color is interpolated (smoothed) to simulate effect of partial fill. This is happens often if you are applying `Effect`. Since you decide do not show us any code you will have to find suitable solution yourself.

Comment: thank you mate. Using RenderOptions.Aliases fixed the blurry borders. Also the UseLayoutRounding helped on some screens.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but for someone with same issue which seems to be the result of using **Effect** in the application like **DropShadowEffect** It solved my issue by adding following line to the Grid/Border ...

```
UseLayoutRounding="True"
```